# Can you convert literal string to an interpolated string in PHP?

Tags: php, eval, string-interpolation

I'm using Kohana to create an e-mail view which is entirely plain text as a part of a MIME Multipart/alternative e-mail. Since plaintext does not really allow for formatting, I want to be able to use interpolated strings to allow escaped characters so I can create new lines, tabs, etc.

However, using Kohana's built in method for rendering a view:

```
View::factory('view_file')->render()
```

always gives me what I believe is a string literal. If I simply create a interpolated string on my own, the escaped characters are created. Using the above method, however, always gives me a literal string so escape codes like `\r` `\t` `\n` appear literally the same in the body of the e-mail.

Is there some way for me to convert the entire string returned by the `render()` method so that it's an interpolated string in PHP?

The reason I want to do this is because I'm using separate views for the HTML and plaintext versions of the e-mail templates, and I want to stick to this convention while being able to use escaped characters in the plaintext version for minimal formatting purposes.

I have already tried embedding the output of the render method into a interpolated string like `$view = "$view"`, but it's my understanding the string gets created and set as it is being made, regardless of whether it's interpolated or literal.

Comment: Nevermind, I can just use the literal string to create the formatting and avoid the use of special characters. Duh...

Comment: I also want to add this: you can still embed interpreted strings (e.g. "string\nhere") into a Kohana view and they will be executed properly. It's very important to distinguish between ' and " when using PHP strings and using special escape codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I interpolate an existing php string literal inside a json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107732/how-can-i-interpolate-an-existing-php-string-literal-inside-a-json-file)