# How can I interpolate an existing php string literal inside a json file?

Tags: php, json

I have a php script , it accessing a json file  by using `file_get_contents()`, inside a json file, we have declared a php variable. Please let me know is there any way to parse the php variable inside a json file.

Below is the code:
test.json

```
{
    "result":"$result",
    "count":3
}
```

php script for accessing the json file

```
<?php
$result = 'Hello';
$event = file_get_contents('test.json');
echo $event;
?>
```

Now the output is like below:

```
{ "result":"$result", "count":3 }
```

But I need the output like this

```
{ "result":"Hello", "count":3 }
```

I'm not able to access the `$result` variable inside a json file.
Any help Appreciated.Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by accessing the `$result` variable?! Please provide a sample of what you want.

Comment: I just googled your query I found this. Not sure but you might get some help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Comment: Your questions is really *"how can I interpolate an existing string literal?"* or something like that

Comment: Don't forget to JSON-escape your `$result` string!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I might get downvoted for this, but could eval be used in this situation?

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "result":"$result",
    "count":3
}'; //replace with file_get_contents("test.json");

$result = 'Hello world';



$test = eval('return "' . addslashes($json) . '";');
echo $test;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/851616f5f17adb):

```
{
    "result":"Hello world",
    "count":3
}
```

Comment: It's the only thing I can think of at the moment as well

Comment: @Phil It's either that, or make up your own parsing scheme (which would be much better than eval IMO).

Comment: Just keep in mind that PHP will interpolate everything starting with `$` and the results may not even be valid JSON anymore.

Answer (score 9):

It's not hard to interpolate this when you parse the structure first; you could then use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk) to iterate over each element in the array and change the value if it matches something that starts with `$`:

```
$json=<<<'JSON'
{
    "result":"$result",
    "count":3
}
JSON;

// parse data structure (array)
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// define replacement context
$context = ['$result' => 'Hello'];
// iterate over each element
array_walk($data, function(&$value) use ($context) {
    // match value against context
    if (array_key_exists($value, $context)) {
        // replace value with context
        $value = $context[$value];
    }
});

echo json_encode($data); // {"result":"Hello","count":3}
```

The obvious advantage is that you don't have to worry about escaping strings so that the JSON format is not violated.

If the data structure is recursive, you could use `array_walk_recursive()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it your way like `{ "result":"$result", "count":3 }`

I would have done like this.

I would have specified a short code for the variable for this

`{ "result":"**result**", "count":3 }`

and when I will get that JSON in PHP, just replace that with my desired PHP variable

```
$event = file_get_contents('test.json');

var $result = "hello";
$parsed_json = str_replace("**result**",  $result,$event  );
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("test.json");
$json_a=json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($json_a as $key => $value){
  echo  $key . ':' . $value;
}
?>
```